# Filter table in D3 from selection in parallel coordinates visualization

Tags: d3.js, filter

I have a parallel coordinates visualization and I've added a table below that represents all the data in the visualization.

I want to filter the table based on the selection of the parallel coordinates visualization. So, just showing the data highlighted in the parallel coordinates visualization.

Any ideas on how to do that?

I've tried in the brush section to highlight the cells in the table in red adding a style in for the  tags, but it doesn't seem to work. See code below:

```
    // Add and store a brush for each axis.
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.svg.brush().y(y[d]).on("brushstart", brushstart).on("brush", brush));
        d3.selectAll("td").style('bgcolor', 'red');
      })
      .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);
```

I've tried to add the highlight of the cells in the brush function. Here I achieve for all the cells to turn red, but I don't know how to highlight only the ones selected in the selection.

```
    function brush() {
      var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) {
          return !y[p].brush.empty();
        }),
        extents = actives.map(function(p) {
          return y[p].brush.extent();
        });
      foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return actives.every(function(p, i) {
          return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
        }) ? null : "none";
      });
      d3.selectAll("td").style('background-color', 'red');
    }
```

See code below, which you can find also in the following link [GitHub](https://github.com/irbp005/ParallelCoordinatesWithTable/blob/master/ParallelCoordinates.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }

  .background path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ddd;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .foreground path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
  }

  .brush .extent {
    fill-opacity: .3;
    stroke: #fff;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .axis line,
  .axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .axis text {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
    cursor: move;
  }

  .tooltip {   
    background-color: rgba(220,220,220,0.5);
    color: #333;
              margin: 10px;
              height: 25px;
              padding-right: 10px;
              padding-left: 10px; 
              padding-top: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius:10px;
        border-radius:10px;
    }

    td, th {
    padding: 1px 4px;
    }

</style>

<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  // Fuente original: https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281
    var margin = {
        top: 30,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 10
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width], 1),
      y = {},
      dragging = {};

    var line = d3.svg.line(),
      axis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left"),
      background,
      foreground;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var notas = [
        {
                "Nombre": "Emily",
                "Matematicas": "10",
                "Ciencias": "10",
                "Historia":  "8",
                "Geografia":  "8",
                "Lengua": "10"
        },
        {
                "Nombre": "Cooper",
                "Matematicas": "10",
                "Ciencias": "7",
                "Historia": "2",
                "Geografia": "8",
                "Lengua": "10"
        }];

    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .text("a simple tooltip")
        .attr("class","tooltip");

    // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
    x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(notas[0]).filter(function(d) {
      return d != "Nombre" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(notas, function(p) {
          return +p[d];
        }))
        .range([height, 0]));
    }));


    // Add grey background lines for context.
    background = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(notas)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

    // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
    foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(notas)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("mouseover", function(n){
        d3.select(this)
        .transition().duration(100)
        .style({'stroke' : '#F00'});
        tooltip.text(n.Nombre);
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
        })
        .on("mousemove", function(){
        return tooltip
            .style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px")
            .style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.select(this)
            .transition().duration(100)
            .style({'stroke': 'steelblue' })
            .style({'stroke-width' : '2'});
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
        });

    // Add a group element for each dimension.
    var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(dimensions)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d) + ")";
      })
      .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function(d) {
          return {
            x: x(d)
          };
        })
        .on("dragstart", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = x(d);
          background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
        })
        .on("drag", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
          foreground.attr("d", path);
          dimensions.sort(function(a, b) {
            return position(a) - position(b);
          });
          x.domain(dimensions);
          g.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + position(d) + ")";
          })
        })
        .on("dragend", function(d) {
          delete dragging[d];
          transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
          transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
          background
            .attr("d", path)
            .transition()
            .delay(500)
            .duration(0)
            .attr("visibility", null);
        }));

    // Add an axis and title.
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d]));
      })
      .append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      });

    // Add and store a brush for each axis.
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.svg.brush().y(y[d]).on("brushstart", brushstart).on("brush", brush));
      })
      .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);

    function position(d) {
      var v = dragging[d];
      return v == null ? x(d) : v;
    }

    function transition(g) {
      return g.transition().duration(500);
    }

    // Returns the path for a given data point.
    function path(d) {
      return line(dimensions.map(function(p) {
        return [position(p), y[p](d[p])];
      }));
    }

    function brushstart() {
      d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    }

    // Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
    function brush() {
      var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) {
          return !y[p].brush.empty();
        }),
        extents = actives.map(function(p) {
          return y[p].brush.extent();
        });
      foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return actives.every(function(p, i) {
          return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
        }) ? null : "none";
      });
    }


// The table generation function
function tabulate(data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select("body").append("table")
            .attr("style", "margin-left: 250px"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

    // append the header row
    thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
            .text(function(column) { return column; });

    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(notas)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .attr("style", "font-family: Courier") // sets the font style
            .html(function(d) { return d.value; });

    return table;
}

// render the table
 var peopleTable = tabulate(notas, ["Nombre", "Matematicas","Ciencias", "Historia","Geografia", "Lengua"]);


  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I've added also the code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ubLu9u8/) but it doesn't display anything. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm not familiar with JSFiddle, so I might be doing something wrong.

I've tried also to use divgrid ([DivGrid](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/3687826)) and with the following code I can see how when I attempt to brush the table gets updated. The problem is that it doesn't get updated with the data I need. I just have it to show 5 records.

```
  <script src="divgrid.js"></script>
  ...
    // Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
    function brush() {
      var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) {
          return !y[p].brush.empty();
        }),
        extents = actives.map(function(p) {
          return y[p].brush.extent();
        });
      foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return actives.every(function(p, i) {
          return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
        }) ? null : "none";
      });
      //d3.selectAll("td").style('background-color', 'red');
       var grid = d3.divgrid();
         d3.select('body')
            .datum(notas.slice(0,5))
            .call(grid);
    }
```

The problems I have (I think) is that (1) the update of the table is not really in the right place as it is only updating when starting to brush, not when brushing over the lines and (2) I need to find a way to pickup the data from the lines that are selected. I've added to code in github as a reference ([GitHub](https://github.com/irbp005/ParallelCoordinatesWithTable/blob/master/ParallelCoordinatesDivGrid.html))

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you can put this in a JSBin, JSFiddle or similar, you are much more likely to get a response.

Comment: Thanks Nic for the advice. I'm not familiar with JSBin/JSFiddle, but I've added the code in GitHub. I hope this helps.